# how to deal with this error,Makefile:1: *** commands commence before first target. Stop

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to use makefile for linking h file and cpp file.

here is the text:

```
    MC : SimpleMCMain1.o Random1.o
        gcc -o MC SimpleMCMain1.o Random1.o

    SimpleMCMain1.o : SimpleMCMain1.cpp Random1.h
        gcc -c SimpleMCMain1.cpp

    Random1.o: Random1.cpp Random1.h
        gcc -c Random1.cpp 

    clean :
        rm MC SimpleMCMain1.o Random1.o
```

I then ran " make " command under the same directory. it gives me an error:

Makefile:1: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.

I need some help on this.

Comment: Is that the full and complete `Makefile`? And is it really indented as shown?

Comment: You should show the file as it really is as even a space is important in a Makefile. If it is indented as you have show, it cannot work

Comment: I tried both in visual studio code and, in the command line I typed nano Makefile, to edit. both method failed. And I am pretty sure I used <tab> for the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could get that message was if I had a non-comment line that was indented with a tab. Like this:

```
echo :
@echo Hello
```

Each line starts with a leading tab. It did NOT produce that error if the first line starts with a space (or even 4 spaces). Note that you get a different error if the second line is indented with 4 spaces instead of a tab.